# How is a gradle task type defined in Kotlin/

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

What is the kotlin Equivalent of the groovy statement

> build.gradle

```
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

in build.gradle.kts

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
tasks.register("clean").configure {
    delete(rootProject.buildDir)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this'll be useful to someone from 2023:

```
tasks.register("clean",Delete::class){
    delete(rootProject.buildDir)
}
```

But `getter for buildDir: File!` is deprecated in Java. Documentation say:

> Use getLayout().getBuildDirectory() instead.

Also from the Docs:

> The build directory is the directory which all artifacts are generated
> into. The default value for the build directory is projectDir/build.